# Button is not working when applying left position attribute in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to position my button at the bottom right of my webpage and have gone through each attribute to rule out the unsuccessful button. I came to realize that when I attempt to position the button using the left attribute, it will no longer work. However, if I do not attempt to use the left attribute it works. Why is this?

```js
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

theme && document.body.classList.add(theme);

document.getElementById('theme-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');

  if (document.body.classList.contains('dark-theme')) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-theme');
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('theme');
  }

});
```

```css
#theme-toggle {
  background-color: #FF5733;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  /*bottom: -1620px;
        left: 1775px;*/
}
```

```html
<button id="theme-toggle">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="sun" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-sun" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M8 11a3 3 0 1 1 0-6 3 3 0 0 1 0 6m0 1a4 4 0 1 0 0-8 4 4 0 0 0 0 8M8 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0m0 13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 13m8-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5M3 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2A.5.5 0 0 1 3 8m10.657-5.657a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-1.414 1.415a.5.5 0 1 1-.707-.708l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0m-9.193 9.193a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707L3.05 13.657a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.707l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0m9.193 2.121a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0l-1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707M4.464 4.465a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L2.343 3.05a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708"/>
            </svg>
        </button>
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what exactly do you mean by that? I've just tested your code with the left attribute and it appears to work as a button for me.

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated on that. When I say it doesn't work, I mean that the webpage is not turning to dark mode. Sure the button reacts to the click, but the page stays in light-mode.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your javascript to the question too please?

Comment: Adam, I have updated with JS.

Comment: looking in devtools is the class `dark-theme` added to `body` indeed?

Comment: IT Goldman, yes the dark-theme toggle is in the <body>

Comment: it's not reproducible in this example, is it? so I can only ask why not use `right: 10px` and `left: unset`

Comment: @ITgoldman using either left or right it generates the same problem -- dark-theme -- doesn't work.

Comment: I can keep it at the top left corner where it started, just not the preferred location on the webpage I wanted.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error, but the code is working fine for me. Even if I apply left css when I click on button and check in localStorage the theme is getting added in LocalStorage. Maybe the error is in your dark-theme class. Share its code.